# find nth element of array in mongo collection? meteor

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection called ChatRooms that has an array of chatIds, which are just the user Ids of who is in the chatroom. There are only two ids in the array at a time.
I want to find the first element in this array and set it to the variable "messager" so that i can see if it belongs to the person currently logged in. if not, the message that was just sent will be added to a different collection called notifications, so that the other user can be notified of receiving a message. I keep getting syntax errors on the query, and I don't know why. Here is my block of code:

```
createMessageNotification = function(message) {
  var messager = ChatRooms.find( {}, { chatIds: { $slice: 0,1 } } );
  //console.log(messager);

  if(messager !== Meteor.userId()){
    Notifications.insert({

      message: message.value
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$slice` needs a scalar or an array parameter. [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) Also you should be doing a `findOne` which returns an object instead of a `find` which returns a cursor.

Try either:

```
var messager = ChatRooms.findOne( {}, { chatIds: { $slice: 1 } } ).chatIds;
```

or

```
var messager = ChatRooms.findOne({}).chatIds[0];
```