# MongoDB issue with updating nested few times object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Hey guys I have got a problem with updating value of key in the collection using Meteor / Mongo

```js
data: {
      'id': id,
      'fb_id': fbId,
      'name': fbName,
      'access_token': fbAccessToken,
      'symbol': fbSymbol,
      'config': {
        'get_started': {
          'payload': getStarted
        },
        'persistent_menu': [
          {
            'locale': 'default',
            'call_to_actions': [
              {
                'type': 'postback',
                'title': persistentMenu1,
                'payload': 'menu'
              },
              {
                'type': 'postback',
                'title': persistentMenu2,
                'payload': 'knowledge_base'
              },
              {
                'type': 'nested',
                'title': persistentMenu3,
                'call_to_actions': [
                  {
                    'type': 'postback',
                    'title': nestedPersistentMenu1,
                    'payload': 'subscription'
                  },
                  {
                    'type': 'postback',
                    'title': nestedPersistentMenu2,
                    'payload': 'tth'
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            'composer_input_disabled': false
          },
          {
            'locale': 'pl_PL',
            'call_to_actions': [
              {
                'type': 'postback',
                'title': persistentMenu1,
                'payload': 'menu'
              },
              {
                'type': 'postback',
                'title': persistentMenu2,
                'payload': 'knowledge_base'
              },
              {
                'type': 'nested',
                'title': persistentMenu3,
                'call_to_actions': [
                  {
                    'type': 'postback',
                    'title': 'Subskrypcja',
                    'payload': 'subscription'
                  },
                  {
                    'type': 'postback',
                    'title': 'Konsultant',
                    'payload': 'tth'
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            'composer_input_disabled': false
          }
        ],
        'greeting': [
          {
            'locale': 'default',
            'text': somethingNew
          },
          {
            'locale': 'pl_PL',
            'text': greetingsText
          }
        ]
      },
      'created_at': '2017-06-05T06:00:37.759455Z',
      'updated_at': updatedAt
    }
  })
```

I need to get to second element in "greeting" array and change value of 'text' which is "greetingsText" at the moment

I tried to do so using console in the browser by typing this code

```
Collection.update({_id: "some_id"}, {$set: {fanpageInfo: {config: {"greeting.2": {text: "tata"}}}}}) but it doesnt work unfortunately
```

there is error saying "update failed:

```
MongoError: The dotted field 'greeting.2' in 'fanpageInfo.config.greeting.2' is not valid for storage."
```

And to be honest I am not sure if I am targeting it properly - I checked docs and asked google but there are just simple tutorials.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: where is `fanpageInfo` field?

Comment: there is fanpageInfo instead of data actually

Comment: check my answer. It works with my query, you can copy paste it in Meteor query, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `greeting` array has only 2 elements, so by using `greeting.2` you're attempting to modify *third* element (zero-based indexes).

Second, you should use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to modify just one particular field:

```
{ $set: { "fanpageInfo.config.greeting.1.text": "tata" } }
```

I've changed `2` to `1` in this update. If you will attempt to use `2` instead — it will create another document in array with just `text: "tata"` inside.

Comment: it will not work. there is nothing like `fanpageInfo` if I did not leave anything unknown.

Comment: @AnkurSoni The question author did tell about that thing: "there is fanpageInfo instead of data actually", so I just assumed that his query is correct, instead of his example data.

Comment: it can be the scenario.

Comment: Thats the solution! thanks a lot mate! Highly appreciated

Comment: @Rachomir Glad it helped :) Don't forget to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**FIND QUERY:**

You need to go through these links as below:

Meteor Specific [find-nth-element-of-array-in-mongo-collection-meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701315/find-nth-element-of-array-in-mongo-collection-meteor)

Mongo Specific [get-n-th-element-of-an-array-in-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223273/get-n-th-element-of-an-array-in-mongodb)

Simple for finding you need to use `slice` like `ChatRooms.findOne( {}, { chatIds: { $slice: 1 } } )`;

**UPDATE QUERY**

You can try

```
Collection.update({_id: "some_id"}, {$set: {'config.greeting.1.text': 'tata'}});
```

> If there is anything at all like `fanpageInfo` as parent field of `config` then update query shall be `Collection.update({_id: "some_id"}, {$set: {'fanpageInfo.config.greeting.1.text': 'tata'}});`

I ran your above data in mongodb and it works fine with above query. Image is below

[image]

For more : [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18065040/3296607)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Appreciated

Comment: Yes mate, and I also learned how to do it in the future :) I would love to give you a point next to answer, however my level is to low

Comment: Also never get demotivated with score, just look ahead to answer and help others, asking fantastic/idiotic questions never really matters. I too learnt something new from your question. So it is win-win situatoin. Make other people's life easy and inspiring. I too started from `ZERO`. So don't bother, be happy and helping here. Stackoverflow have great helping people like @Styx, @jankapankt, @michel floyd, @mikkel whom I know they solve issues immediately and unconditionally, I learnt from them to be unconditional and humble. So fly high :)